# How to compare string and integer in python?

Tags: python, comparison

I have this simple python program. I ran it and it prints `yes`, when in fact I expect it to not print anything because `14` is not greater than `14`.

I saw this [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int) question, but it isn't very helpful.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys

hours = "14"

if (hours > 14):
        print "yes"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Convert the string to an integer with `int`:

```
hours = int("14")

if (hours > 14):
        print "yes"
```

In CPython2, when comparing two non-numerical objects of different types, the comparison is performed by comparing the *names* of the types. Since `'int' < 'string'`, *any int is less than any string*.

```
In [79]: "14" > 14
Out[79]: True

In [80]: 14 > 14
Out[80]: False
```

This is a classic Python pitfall. In Python3 this wart has been corrected -- comparing non-numerical objects of different type raises a TypeError by default.

As [explained in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons):

> CPython implementation detail: Objects of different types except
>   numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types
>   that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way is to convert `hours` to an integer is by using `int(hours)`.

```py
hours = "14"

if int(hours) > 14:
    print("yes")
```