# Using a loop to create multiple drop down menus

Tags: python, loops, button, tkinter

I am trying to use a loop to create multiple drop down menus based on an entry in a entry text box after submit is pressed. I have never worked with tkinter before so I am not sure if I am doing this correctly. Any help would be appreciated. the code I have below is what I have but it causes the program to enter into some kind of infinite loop

```
from Tkinter import *

def callback():
    numQues = E1.get()
    i = 0
    while i < numQues:
        variable = StringVar(top)
        variable.set("Short Answer") # default value
        w = OptionMenu(top, variable, "Short Answer", "Multiple Choice", "Fill in the Blank",
                  "True of False", "Mathcing", "Ordering") 
        w.grid(row = i+1, column=0)
        i = i+1

top = Tk()
top.geometry("600x600")
L1 = Label(top, text="How many questions will the quiz be?")
L1.grid(row=0, column=0)
E1 = Entry(top, bd = 5)
E1.grid(row=0, column=1)

MyButton1 = Button(top, text="Submit", width=10, command=callback)
MyButton1.grid(row=1, column=1)

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is python 2, isn't it.

Comment: hint: `i` is an integer, `numQues` is a string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare string and integer in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661829/how-to-compare-string-and-integer-in-python)

Comment: It is python 2 and okay let me convert things over and see if that helps some

Comment: converted the numQues to an int and got it to work! thank you!

Comment: One other question. How do I access the chosen menu option from the drop down menu?