# Assistance with issue

Tags: python

While writing some code for a class, it gave this error and I don't know how to fix it as I personally do not see any issues with what it is addressing

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Daniel Benotti\Desktop\School\Benotti_Daniel student Ed loop with functions.py", line 50, in 
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Daniel Benotti\Desktop\School\Benotti_Daniel student Ed loop with functions.py", line 9, in main
    TotCurr, TotCe = loop(TotCurr, TotCe, again)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel Benotti\Desktop\School\Benotti_Daniel student Ed loop with functions.py", line 21, in loop
    TotCurr, TotCe, studType = calc(studNum, TotCurr, TotCe)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel Benotti\Desktop\School\Benotti_Daniel student Ed loop with functions.py", line 34, in calc
    if studNum > STUD_NUMBER:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`enter code here`
```

this is the code that follows

```
STUD_NUMBER = 2500

def main():
    TotCurr, TotCe, again = init()
    TotCurr, TotCe = loop(TotCurr, TotCe, again)
    dispTot(TotCurr, TotCe)

def init():
    TotCurr = 0
    TotCe = 0
    again = "Y"
    return TotCurr, TotCe, again

def loop(TotCurr, TotCe, again):
    while again.upper() == "Y":
        firstName, lastName, studNum = getInput()
        TotCurr, TotCe, studType = calc(studNum, TotCurr, TotCe)
        dispDetail(studType)
        again = input("Do you want to add another student record? (Y/N): ")
        print()
    return TotCurr, TotCe

def getInput():
    firstName = input("please enter students first name: ")
    lastName = input("please enter students last name: ")
    studNum = input("please enter the student ID number: ")
    return firstName, lastName, studNum

def calc(studNum, TotCurr, TotCe):
    if studNum > STUD_NUMBER:
        studType = "Curriculum"
        TotCurr += 1
    else:
        studType = "Continuing Education"
        TotCe +=1
    return TotCurr, TotCe, studType

    def dispdetail(studType):
        print("This student is currently in the", studType, 'course')
        print()

    def dispTot(TotCurr, TotCe):
        print("Total students in Cuuriculum course", TotCurr)
        print("Total students in Continuing education course", TotCe)

main()
enter code here
```

Comment: Hi @DonniBenotti could you add your code?

Comment: Just did sir @DanielMasejo

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're comparing a String and an Integer

do this:

```
if int(studNum) > STUD_NUMBER:
```

This is called casting. You will be converting a string to an int by using this function: `int()`

[How to compare string and integer in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661829/how-to-compare-string-and-integer-in-python)

Comment: I fixed that and now its telling me that my dispDetail isn't defined which it is

Comment: You're calling it before it being defined.

Python is an interpreted language. Put that in mind when declaring functions after calling them.

Further reading: https://www.quora.com/How-does-the-Python-interpreter-handle-function-calls-in-lines-before-the-actual-function-definition-without-using-forward-declarations-like-in-C++

Comment: Thats the strange thing though, as I have another set of the code that has that same setup, but it works.

Comment: The functions defined inside the function are also defined after a return. That code is unreachable. Put it outside.

Comment: I see it now. It was an indentation error. those always get me

Comment: This pyhton class has been fun so far, but im not so quick on the uptake and some small things I miss really easily at times or I just dont get at all, so I appreciate the help