# Why is my function returning None when I clearly have defined it to do otherwise? This is a basic function for calculating the area of shapes

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I am currently writing a short program for my intro to computer science course, and my code is returning "none" even though I am pretty sure my definitions are clear. Don't mind the bulky naming for my functions and stuff, its a course requirement. The objective of the code is to be able to choose a shape and then directly input the required information without a written prompt, and then the program will RETURN the area of the chosen shape. I have been breaking my teeth over this for the past few hours, playing with it, but my code is returning none regardless of what I do. Any advice? Please refrain from blatantly giving me new code because I can get in trouble for that, just perhaps point me in the direction of my problem.

```
import math

# the following functions are built to calculate each shape

def circle_area(rad):
    return math.pi*rad**2

def rectangle_area(side_one, side_two):
    return side_one*side_two

def triangle_area(edge):
    return (math.sqrt(3)/4)*(edge**2)

# the following function as assigned using the above functions

def shape_area():

    shape_choice = input("Choose shape (1=circle, 2=rectangle, 3=triangle):")

    if shape_choice == 1 or 3:
        length_one = input("")

    elif shape_choice == 2:
        length_two, length_three = input("")

    if shape_choice == 1:
        circle_area(length_one)

    elif shape_choice == 2:
        rectangle_area(length_two, length_three)

    elif shape_choice == 3:
        triangle_area(length_one)

    elif shape_choice != 1 or 2 or 3:
        return None
```

I'm not sure why all my code isn't going into the specific code gray box, but I hope my code is more or less clear.

Comment: Your shape_area() function will always return None. Most of the routes through it fall out of the bottom and return None by default.

Comment: I am not familiar with python, but you only have a return statement and that is the return None

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Function Returning None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471876/python-function-returning-none)

Comment: From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) input function returns string. Would [How to compare string and integer in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661829/how-to-compare-string-and-integer-in-python) thread be useful?

Answer (score 5):

You are not returning the area values, just calculating them.

```
    if shape_choice == 1:
        return circle_area(length_one)

    elif shape_choice == 2:
        return rectangle_area(length_two, length_three)

    elif shape_choice == 3:
        return triangle_area(length_one)
```

Also, as @NomadMonad also mentions, the statement:

```
if shape_choice == 1 or 3:
```

is always true as `3` is a thing. Instead use `if shape_choice == 1 or shape_choice == 3:`

Your final `elif` can be an `else` as it is the final condition that can be returned. You could even remove it as python will return `None` if nothing is returned anyway.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that because the function itself dictates a return that it would work without returning the actual function

Comment: Another option is: if shape_choice in [1, 3]:

Comment: You can imagine a function as having a value, the value is whatever it returns. A good way of thinking about it is, if I copy the code from the function instead of calling the function, and then remove the return statement, that is what you get. Some values / variables for you to use.

Comment: `if shape_choice in {1,3};`

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
if shape_choice == 1 or 3
```

Always evaluates to `True`

You should change it to

```
if shape_choice == 1 or shape_choice == 3
```

Similarly

```
elif shape_choice != 1 or 2 or 3
```